# How does windows task manager performance tab fetches CPU GPU VPU and Memory utilization/Usage

Tags: windows, operating-system, wmi, taskmanager, psutil

where is the task manager is getting this data and how it is mapping to particular device.
basically i'm trying to write a script which fetches the CPU GPU VPU utilization from task manager. We have Psutil for cpu and we have Performance counter for gpu but there is not module or perf counter for vpu.can anybody help me understand how task manager works and how do i fetch intel VPU utilization from a python script.

Answer (score 2):

Task Manager gets the CPU and GPU straight from the motherboard and bios. Some motherboards allow third party access and others don't. So to bridge the Gap in perfmon and wmi they only access that info if the manufacturer of the motherboard allows it.

I had this same question and so I called the manufacturer and they said they do not allow access to the driver that holds this information but only allows it to certified software distribution (example: Microsoft).

The only work around for this is to take the speed shown on perfmon divide it by Active Cores and then multiply it by pi. This will give you an average speed (638393) from the you have to math it up to the percentage of how many cores the processor or GPU uses that you won't know because each motherboard is different on how many cores is being used.

So long story short... Having an Accurate value for GPU and CPU is based on the allowance from the motherboard if you can access the info from the driver.

Hope this helps, this was explained to me years ago by a Computer and Software Engineering department for ASUS motherboards..

The only other work around is pull the information from the bios and add 2 to it, to get an 88% accuracy.